# Resolve Merge Conflicts in Bitbucket where I do not have permission to push to either source or destination branch

Tags: git, merge, bitbucket, merge-conflict-resolution

We have a setup where we do PRs into develop branch ... On merge this gets deployed to our staging/test environment ... I do not have permission to push changes directly to this branch ... There is a master branch and when changes from develop are merged into this one ... they get deployed to production environment ... I do not have permission to push changes directly to this branch either ... I pushed a few feature branches and merged them into develop through PRs ... Now when I create a PR to merge develop into master bitbucket says cannot merge as there are merge conflicts ... How do I resolve them?

Additional Info: Just checked and the master branch somehow is 5 commits ahead of develop. Not sure how that came to be.

What I have tried so far ... Locally I got the latest from develop and master ... Merged master into develop ... resolved the conflicts ... committed changes ... unable to push them to develop since I do not have permissions to do so ... Stuck with this ... Any assistance is welcome.

Comment: Resolve the conflict ... through the Bitbucket web interface ... ?

Comment: I do not see any options to do so ... It just says that to merge changes I need to resolve conflicts manually ... followed by a link that says Learn More ... This describes an approach that does not work for me ...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch from your resolved local version of `develop` and push it. Create a PR from that branch into `develop`. Once approved & merged this will carry the conflict-resolution changes into `develop` and make it able to be merged into `master` via PR.

Comment: I created a branch off of develop. Merged changes and resolved conflicts with master. I pushed it and created a PR to merge it into develop. After merge I tried to merge develop into master through PR but it still shows the same conflicts.

Comment: Were any commits squashed?

Comment: No! None of the commits were squashed.

Comment: Added additional information to the question.